# HTML Jquery Navigation "active"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I have a navigation menu which the style of the elements change if i click on them..they get the class "active".
I have a dropdown Menu in my navigation, how can i make it that the drop down title get the class and not only the elements at the dropdown. Here my [page](http://nitram0598.zapto.org/).

Here is the code for the navigation:

```
            $('#content').children('section').not('#home').hide();   
            $('.active:has(a.anavigation-element)').not('.navbar-brand').not('#home').removeClass('active');      
            $(".a").click(function(e){
                var $this = $(this);
                e.preventDefault();

                if ($(this).hasClass('navigation-element')){
                    var $target = $('#' + $(this).attr('href')).stop(true, true);
                    var $secs = $('#content > section').not($target).stop(true, true).filter(':visible');
                    if ($secs.length) {
                        $('.active:has(a.navigation-element)').not('.navbar-brand').removeClass('active');
                        $this.not('.navbar-brand').parent().addClass('active');
                        $secs.fadeOut(function () {
                            $target.fadeIn();
                        });
                    } else {
                        $this.not('.navbar-brand').parent().addClass('active');
                        $target.fadeIn();
                    }
                } else if ($(this).hasClass('hide')){
                    $(this).parent().fadeOut();
                }
            });
```

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Have you solved this yet? If not, can you make a fiddle with your content and I can take a look at it, and do my best to help :).